# nginx rewrite in another location with path parameters

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I have this locations in my Nginx server:

```
location ~ /myapipath/1.0.0/user/(.*)/(.*)
{
  if ( $arg_movieId )
  {
    rewrite ^ /$1/$2/getUserDetails;
  }
  alias /myfolder/$1/$2/getUser.json;
}
    
location /(.*)/(.*)/getUserDetails
{
  alias /myfolder/$1/$2/getUserDetails.json;
}
```

If I call the API without query parameter, it works and returns the getUser.json file content:
request: `curl https://mydns/myapipath/1.0.0/user/will/smith`
response: `{"name":"will","surname":"smith"}`

If I call the API with query parameter, it returns the error 404 instead to get the getUserDetails.json:
request: `https://mydns/myapipath/1.0.0/user/will/smith?movieId=001`
response: `404 Not Found`

How I can use the rewrite function with path parameters to get the getUserDetails.json file correctly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In your `rewrite` statement the regular expression `^` contains no captures, therefore the values of `$1` and `$2` will be empty. They will not contain the values of the captures from the regular expression in the `location` statement.

Comment: I tried this rewrite but no result: `rewrite ^/user/(.*)/(.*) /$1/$2/getUserDetails;`

Comment: That regular expression does not match the URI you are attempting to rewrite. The URI does not **begin with** `/user/`, it begins with `/myapipath/1.0.0/user/`. The `^` is an anchor for the beginning of the string being tested.

Comment: I resolved with this code:
`location ~ /myapipath/1.0.0/user/(.*)/(.*)
{
  if ( $arg_movieId )
  {
    rewrite ^/myapipath/1.0.0/user/(.*)/(.*) /$1/$2/getUserDetails;
  }
  alias /myfolder/$1/$2/getUser.json;
}
    
location ~ /(.*)/(.*)/getUserDetails
{
  alias /myfolder/$1/$2/getUserDetails.json;
}`

Thanks for your support.